# How can I recreate this fade-opacity-on-scroll, fixed background design?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

The design in question is: http://hthworldwide.net/

I'm specifically trying to recreate the landing/hero element that fades opacity on scroll to reveal the fixed image in the background.

I've gotten sort of close, but I can't seem to nail this thing down. The problem is that I can't get the white filter to stretch across the whole screen without giving a white background to the transparent letters. Ideally you should be able to see the background image through the text as shown in the example.

Here is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/rsprice/pen/reVazo

html:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="opacity-layer"></div>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-position: 0px -300px;
  background-size: 130%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=a9504411622da8e65df977606f82479c');
}

.opacity-layer {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 2000px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background: url('http://hthworldwide.net/sites/all/themes/hthworldwide/style/images/home-intro.png') no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.text img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.other {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".opacity-layer").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code, it is not only done with a single `div` but with a table.

It looks like this:

```
+--+--------------------+--+
|  |                    |  |
+--+--------------------+--+
|  |  TRANSPARENT TEXT  |  |
+--+--------------------+--+
|  |                    |  |
+--+--------------------+--+
```

And the code is like this (simplified):

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="centerCell"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
   <table>
</div>
```

**All the cells in that table have a white background but the center one** (that holds the white image with the transparent text). Also, the center cell is the only one that has the width set, so the others will occupy the rest of the table/window. Then when the page scrolls, instead of changing the opacity of the image layer, you change the opacity of the `div` that contains the whole table.

This is almost how you have it in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/rsprice/pen/reVazo) (not in the code from the question), you just need to change a little bit the code to fit it:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".container table").css("opacity", .95 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=a9504411622da8e65df977606f82479c');
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 0px -300px;
  background-size: 130%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  background:url(http://hthworldwide.net/sites/all/themes/hthworldwide/style/images/background-home-hk2.jpg);
}

#text {
  height: 300px;
  width: 980px;
  background-position: center;
  background: url('http://hthworldwide.net/sites/all/themes/hthworldwide/style/images/home-intro.png') no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  
}

td {
  opacity: .95;
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
}

#footer { height:1000px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="text"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Alvaro! I really appreciate it.